# Calling ToString() gotchas

Tags: c#

I have read that ToString() uses reflection (although it should just put quotation marks around the object it is called on so I don't know where/why it may use reflection). Is there any proof of this? And is there any performance penalty of calling .ToString() (maybe I should call Convert.ToString()?)?

Comment: "Put quotation marks around the object it is called on" ? What do you mean by that... I feel like this is a wrong conception...

Comment: I think he means if you had an object called duka and you had duka d = new duka();
d.ToString() would return 'duka'

Comment: @taylonr: If that were the case, it would *definitely* require reflection.

Comment: Calling `Convert.ToString(...)` internally calls an object's `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't override the `ToString()` method, you end up calling `Object.ToString()`, whose implementation looks something like this:

```
public virtual string ToString()
{
    return this.GetType().ToString();
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecuritySafeCritical]
public extern Type GetType();
```

The method doesn't simply "put quotation marks around the object it is called on". In order to accomplish that result, it must reflectively get the runtime type information and call `ToString()` on that, which in turn looks something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return ("Type: " + this.Name);
}
```

Anytime you go through reflection for something there is a bit of a performance penalty, but in this case probably not one large enough to really matter - unless you are doing it inside of a very tight, very large loop.

Are you seeing a performance problem? What are you trying to accomplish that is leading you to want to call `Object.ToString()` rather than calling an overridden version that you provide?

Comment: Thanks. Good detail in your answer +1

Comment: btw this is just a theoretical question, no use case.

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you don't override ToString() that is where it ends up using reflection.

If you had:

```
public class SomeObject 
{
   public void  SomeMethod();
}

void program
{
  SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
  Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
}
```

You would have to use reflection to know what type of object o is.
Now, if you override ToString() which you should do to have a meaningful string representation, then the code you write will get called directly w/o reflection.

Comment: Actually the default implementation doesn't use reflection. It calls GetType() which is marked as an InternalCall e.g. functionality built directly into the CLR. So even that code path shouldn't hit any reflection based performance penalties.